# CakePHP join queries don't fire on Dreamhost

Tags: cakephp, dreamhost

My CakePHP site works perfectly in my dev environment which is XAMPP with PHP 5.3.1.  I pushed up my site to Dreamhost where I host all my sites and discovered the join queries are not firing so I'm not getting a complete data set to loop through on the views of my controllers.  I'm using PHP 5.3 with Dreamhost.  My static pages display fine as do controllers which have no relationships with other tables.

Any suggestions as to why it's failing on Dreamhost, but working fine in my development environment?

Comment: You clear your cache? The latest models on Dreamhost?

Answer (score 2):

Solved.  My model file names were capitalized as in Ingredient.php when it should have been ingredient.php.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1001/Understanding-Models